# How do relational databases work with a REST API?

Tags: rest, api, relational-database

I'm trying to understand how a REST API would work when dealing with a relational, normalized database. For example, given the tables `Customer`, `Order`, and `OrderType`:

```
Customer
   ID
   Name
   Address

Order
   ID
   Amount
   TypeId
   CustomerId

Order Type
   ID
   Desc
```

If I wanted to lookup all the order information for a given customer, I would do something like `url/customers/:customerId/orders`; and in the the API it would handle performing joins on tables in order to return a response like this?

```
{
   "orderNumber": 123,
   "type": "online",
   "customer": "john doe",
   "amount": "500"
},
{
   "orderNumber": 124,
   "type": "in-store",
   "customer": "jane doe",
   "amount": "100"
}
```

Is that correct? Or would I need to do separate API calls such as `url/customers/:customerId`, `url/orders/:customerId`, and `url/orderType/:typeId` then assemble the information in the front end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assemble information on front end you lose most benefits of relational database and have to write lots of code instead of one line of sql. You design your API routes according to specific tasks you want to perform, which does not depend on application architecture and what stack of technologies you use.

Comment: So the concept of a REST API is still very new to me. If I understand correctly, I would be setting up (for example) `url/customer/:customerId/orders` so that this specific route in the API would return the assembled object (formatted as JSON) from the first part of my question? As in how I would with a SQL statement of `select * from customers c where c.id = 1 inner join orders o on o.CustomerId = c.ID`; correct?